# Firebase: Quota Exceeded (Cloud Storage Network (Egress) - Americas and EMEA)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

[image: My quota usage information]

Can somebody please explain what is that mean?
How could my Cloud Storage Network (Egress) - Americas and EMEA quota exceeded? Is it just because too much network request from Asia?

Comment: If you have questions about billing or reporting in the Firebase console, you should contact Firebase support directly. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: You have used 1.13 GB of a 1 GB quota. Your solution will be to upgrade your account from `free` to `paid`.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, I know. But, it is not about billing or reporting. I want to know about that egress thing.

Comment: @JohnHanley How can that's the only one that exceeded?

Comment: Without details on your services how can we answer? Someone, somewhere read 1.13 GB of data from objects in your storage bucket. That one item is easy to exceed. Data read means reading data from an object (and other secondary data transfer items).

Comment: @JohnHanley Okay i got it. Thank you for your response, John. :)

Comment: @JohnHanley i have the same issue. So do I understand right that this particular quota means how much data was read from Firebase Storage?

Comment: @FarisHan hey man did you optimize it and make it work?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov - Yes that is how much data was read from Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: @JohnHanley how it can be improved? any ideas where to look at?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov No, I didn't optimize and didn't made it. I moved it to other service.

Comment: @FarisHan could you please let me know the service you moved to?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov I moved to mLab (MongoDB)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have network usage of free limit exceeded.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#internet_egress

Upgrade your plan to blaze or flame.
I think must have video or high resolution i images in your app.